# Can't install nvidia driver on my laptop anymore

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I had installed Nvidia driver on my MSI pe60 6qe laptop (GTX 960 M) running ubuntu 16.04 using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` but had performance issues, so I decided to use the proprietary driver. While it was getting installed, my laptop accidentally shut down. Now after rebooting, I can't neither install the open source driver nor the proprietary one: the installation process never ends. What should I do?

Comment: The "Nvidia" driver is the proprietary driver (the open-source driver is "nouveau"). Please edit your question with the bare minimum: MSI PE60 E has a Nvidia GTX960M (so other don't have to google like I did), what driver version you attempted to install. What do you see now after rebooting. *I can't neither install the open source driver nor the proprietary one* is at first glance nonsensical so please explain with more deatils what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The `nividia-current` does not install the latest Nvidia driver as its name suggests. It install the current long term support Nvidia driver which unsurprisingly doesn't work for GTX960M.

According to [Nvidia](http://www.geforce.com/drivers) the only suitable driver versions are: 352, 361, 367 and 370 (currently beta). Keep this in mind for later.

Now, regarding your issue, first of all, you don't need to install the open-source driver `nouveau` because it is already installed and will be used by default in the absence of other (proprietary) drive.

Start with removing all traces of previous attempts at Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*

sudo reboot now
```

At this point the open-source should be up and running like in a freshly installed Ubuntu.

Open Additional Drivers, select and apply the recommended version only (check above the suitable versions). Reboot.

Comment: the first line gives the error 'E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.'

Comment: So please do it before anything else. It's a symptom that you really messed things up but unrelated to the question being answered.